# О корне в слове «наставник»

Tags: морфемный-разбор, корень-слова

В слове "наставник" дочь выделила корень *-став-*, а не *-настав-*.
Корректно ли так разобрать?
Учительница выделила как ошибку. Кто прав?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> В слове "наставник" дочь выделила корень -*став*-, а не -*настав*-.
> Корректно ли так разобрать?

Если Ваша дочь сможет обосновать родственность слов ***ставить*** и ***наставить/наставлять/наставник/наставница***… – то можно и так разбирать.

В качестве аргументов при разговоре с учителем она может использовать эти словари:

---

**Потиха З.А. «Школьный словообразовательный словарь». Волгоград, 1961:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P. S.** Правда, в вышедших позже своих словарях Потиха выделял уже в этих словах корень ***настав/наставл***.

---

**Панов Б.Т., Текучев А.В. «Школьный грамматико-орфографический словарь русского языка». М., 1985:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**P. S.** Правда, в более поздних изданиях этого словаря выделяется уже корень ***настав/наставл***.

---

**Баранов М.Т. «Школьный орфографический словарь русского языка». М., 2015:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148136/discussion-on-answer-by------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Comment: @Ajgy  В качестве реплики. Вам очень понравился этот ответ? А о чем здесь говорится? О том, что два лингвиста перешли на сторону семантического разбора НАСТАВ-, хотя раньше выделяли приставку НА. Школьный словарь Баранова (1924- 1999) – это вообще раритет, его исправлять никто не будет. В нем отражена методика  прошлого века, хотя ссылка дана на 2015 год. И однозначный вывод; семантический разбор НАСТАВ- более  АКТУАЛЕН, поэтому он и обозначен на всех учебных сайтах. Кому нужно с этим спорить. На месте ученика я бы не стала.

Comment: @sharon Такой разбор актуален только для вас. Увы, но это правда.

Comment: @Ajgy  Для меня да. Правда, еще обозначен в словарях и на большинстве учебных сайтов. Но это так, мелочи.

Comment: @Sharon, мне думается, что человек, написавший в этой теме, что «_в толковом словаре уже есть глагол **наставить** (научить), он стал **самостоятельным,** получил собственную словарную статью. Поэтому при разборе мы **включаем приставку НА** в состав корня_», не должен был бы давать советы школьникам по морфемному разбору и словообразовательному разборам. Не дай бог кто-то из школьников воспользуется его утверждениями!

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо, что быстро отреагировали на этот мой комментарий и убрали имевшую место в своём ответе чушь, которая почему-то получила два плюса на этом сайте!

Comment: @Слава Спасибо, замечание принято, я поправила текст, выделив другой важный момент. ЧУШЬ в ответах и в голосовании мы обсуждать не будем, это неконструктивно, а сама оценка крайне невежлива (я экспрессивной и недружественной лексикой не пользуюсь). А можно вам конструктивный вопрос? Если выделять приставку НА., то какой способ образования слова наставить (научить)?

Comment: @Sharon, перечитайте ещё раз ответ, данный ранее Ajgy. По-моему, его сравнение глагола _наставить_  с глаголом _ставить_  из фразы  _ставить на определенную дорогу, путь_  выглядит очень убедительным для обоснования родственности этих глаголов.

Comment: @Слава  Меня интересует короткий ответ для словообразовательного разбора, какую формулировку вы предложите. Там нужно просто назвать способ как терминологическое название. Описание (обоснование)  Ajgy для этой цели не подойдет. Надо выбрать общепринятый ТЕРМИН

Comment: Вы просто предложите термин (ваш вариант), а обсуждать его не будем. Коротко назовите.

Comment: @Sharon, разрешите напомнить Вам комментарий, полученный мной  от Вас в одной из последних тем: «_Думаю, что могу, но не буду. Зачем мне это надо? Бессмысленная трата времени: вы все равно ничего не поймете, да и зачем я буду о вас заботиться. Так что до свидания, Слава_». До свидания, Sharon.

Comment: @Слава  Вы пишете мою биографию: Очень польщена. А если у вас ответа нет (вы еще не выбрали термин), то я могу и на форуме задать вопрос. Может, кто и ответит, Ajgy например.  До свидания, Слава.

Comment: @Слава  И по поводу УТОЧНЕНИЯ, которое я внесла в ответ по вашему комментарию. Я не убрала из текста «собственную  словарную статью»  (эту «чушь», как вы сказали), а поставила ее на второе место. Изменение значения  определяется по новому СМЫСЛУ слова, а собственная статья — это уже следствие такого изменения и дополнительный его признак.

Answer (score 3):

Не стоит верить ответам, написанным выше. Язык - это живые связи, а живые связи могут сохраняться в языке долгое время. Если для носителя языка они понятны, то и разбор более чем корректен, пусть даже корифеи, например Тихонов, заявляют обратное: корень ***"став"*** здесь нельзя выделить, можно только **"настав"**.

---

В данном случае ***опрощения не произошло***, поскольку связь со словом "ставить" не утрачена. Таким образом, цепочка будет такой:
ставить - на/ставить - настав/ник.

---

Как это можно доказать? "**Наставить**" - это ***ставить*** на определенную дорогу, путь. Значение приставки **"на"** здесь чувствуется (направленность действия), и это нельзя назвать **историей слова**, поскольку связь вполне актуальна. Об истории можно говорить, например, в случае с "начало", "набалдашник".

---

Соответственно, ваша дочь **не сделала никакой ошибки**: корень **"став"** здесь можно и нужно выделить. Глупость - верить необоснованным мнениям. Кроме того, я не раз уточнял информацию у специалистов "Грамоты.ру" по поводу таких случаев, как этот. Цитирую их ответ: "Морфемика - очень спорная область лингвистики, если ребенок может доказать свой ответ, то нельзя его считать неверным".

---

P.S. С каких пор аргументом стало то, что в словаре присутствует слово с приставкой?

Comment: Ребенку в школе следует знать правильный ответ в соответствии со школьными требованиями, а то он получит плохую оценку на ЕГЭ.  Надо знать, где можно спорить, а где не надо. И желательно иметь ссылку на авторитетный УЧЕБНИК школьного уровня.   А корифеи и специалисты пусть себе разбираются. Хотите поучаствовать? Тогда тоже приводите ссылки на специалистов. Это спорный вопрос? Докажите, почему спорный, только без эмоций, please. Задайте отдельный вопрос на форуме, тогда найдете для себя собеседников,  а этот вопрос был на  школьную.ю тему.

Comment: @Sharon Кто сказал, что ваш ответ правильный? Если уж говорить начистоту, то правильного варианта в этом вопросе не было. Почему? Потому что можно опираться на Тихонова и соглашаться с ним (как сделали вы), включая в состав корня приставку, а можно  и не включать, мотивируя это живой связью между словами (как сделал я). Я выразил свое мнение по этому поводу. Любой толковый словарь, в котором говорится о направленности действия в слове "ставить", уже будет авторитетом, это понятно и так: не вижу смысла приводить еще какие-то данные.

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос на форуме и обсудите его. Здесь обсуждается школьная тема, о есть как принято в школе, как нужно отвечать на экзамене.

Comment: Если вы не знали, то на ЕГЭ именно поэтому и нет вопросов по морфемике: большинство вариантов разбора не имеет однозначной трактовки и никакой "школьный учебник" не может быть авторитетом в этом случае. И напоминаю вам, что комментарии тут запрещены, вы сами говорили об этом. Так что можете отразить все свои негодования в СВОЕМ ответе.

Comment: Нет так нет, но есть другие проверки и школьные нормы.  Эти нормы тоже надо знать. Ученик может спросить у учителя, почему надо выделять корень НАСТАВ. Ну для начала, а потом сам подумает и т.д. Так строится правильный учебный процесс.

Comment: Мне перенести свои комментарии в отдельный ответ? Ведь один ответ я уже дала. Могу вместе с вашими, если вы не возражаете))

Comment: @sharon И какой же есть уникальный способ проверки, неведомой доселе? Проверка именно так и делается: сопоставляют анализируемое слово с производящим. Если в языке связь осталась, значит объяснить производное с помощью производящего можно. Это означает, что морфема в составе есть, если нет - непроизводное. Связь осталась, вы сами о ней написали в своем ответе, почему вы решили, что это история слова? Есть вполне логичная фраза: ставить на путь истины. "Наставить" пошло именно отсюда.

Answer (score 2):

Формально права, конечно, **учительница**, но ученика тоже **надо понять.** Или, другими словами, научить, как правильно делать выбор. И это тоже обязанность учителя.

Дело в том, что у глагола «наставить» **два значения**, это можно посмотреть  в толковом словаре на Грамота. ру.  Мы выбираем значение **«научить»**, именно от этого глагола образуется  сущ. «наставник».

**А какая же связь с глаголом  «ставить»?**  От этого глагола образовался глагол «наставить», а приставка НА здесь обозначает **направленность действия** в сторону изучения какого-то предмета.

Такова **историческая связь слов.** Но в толковом словаре уже есть глагол ***наставить*** (научить),  он стал **самостоятельным**, получил собственную словарную статью. **Но почему?**

Здесь нужно отметить очень **важный момент**: именно в глаголе "наставить" со значением "научить" мы уходим от пространственного значения глагола "ставить" к другому **СМЫСЛОВОМУ** значению.

**Приложение**

Значение 1. **НАСТАВИТЬ**, св. 1. что и кого-чего. **Поставить, расположить,** разместить где-л. в каком-л. (обычно большом) количестве. Н. десяток сторожей у каждой двери. Наставили тут мебели - не пройдёшь! И еще 4 значения.

Значение 2. **НАСТАВИТЬ**, св. (кого) на что и чему. Книжн. **Научить** кого-л. чему-л. хорошему; дать наставления (2 зн.). Н. заблудшего на путь истинный. Н. добру и правде. Н. на ум (разг.; вразумить). <Наставлять, -яю, -яешь; нсв. Наставление (см.).

**НАСТАВНИК**, -а; м. Воспитатель, учитель. Молодёжный н. Н. юношества. Классный н. (в России до 1917 г.: классный воспитатель в гимназии, реальном училище). Н. сборной команды по футболу. Мастер-наставник. Капитан-наставник (во флоте).

**СТАВИТЬ**, нсв. (св. поставить). 1. что. Придавать чему-л. стоячее положение, **располагать**, укреплять в стоячем положении. С. мачту, антенну. С. телеграфные столбы. С. лестницу к стене. **С. книги** в шкаф.

**НА**...; приставка. I. (служит для образования глаг.). 1. Указывает на направленность движения, действия в сторону или на поверхность предмета.

Comment: а как в итоге правильно? Все разное говорят...

Comment: А кто все?  Нужно прислушиваться к авторитетным мнениям. Тихонов – это убедительное доказательство, и учитель придерживается этого мнения. А кто против него? Надо смотреть источники и ссылки.  Лингвисты могут иметь разные мнения, но учебный школьный вариант должен быть один. Кстати, в каком классе учится ваша дочь?  Даже это важно. Иногда в специализированных школах обсуждают разные варианты, но на собственную языковую логику можно ориентироваться с определенного возраста.

Comment: А вы сами как думаете?  Какие доводы вам кажутся убедительными?

Comment: 9 класс. Я не эксперт не могу знать.

Comment: Да, 9 класс – это уже ОГЭ. Там будет разбор слов по составу? Тогда нужно не спорить с учителем, а узнать у него школьную норму. Просто поговорить с ним, почему он считает такой разбор правильным. И спросить: именно так надо разбирать на экзамене? Тогда он должен дать корректный и продуманный ответ.

Comment: насколько я знаю этот прихоти учительницы. Именно разборов нет экзамене.

Comment: Пусть так. Но это же ваш учитель, и этот разбор есть У Тихонова, а это авторитетный словарь. Школьнику 9 класса лучше использовать его, а не какие-то новые разработки лингвистов. Вряд ли они соответствуют базовой программе школы.

Comment: Поняла, спасибо

Answer (score 2):

**Второй ответ** (как найти корень слова в общем случае)

В лингвистике существует понятие **«исторический  корень»**. Этимологи, к примеру, выделяют в слове и.-е. корень для слов этой языковой группы. Очевидно, что таким корнем является корень ***ста/сто,*** который мы видим в словах *стать, стоять, становиться, ставить, **наставить***  и т.д. При современном разборе слов по составу мы эти исторические связи не учитываем.

Но есть еще **словообразовательный разбор**, где нужно понимать словообразовательную **цепочку**, то есть исходное слово, от которого образованы другие слова и способы образования этих слов. Такая общая цепочка является тоже **исторической** (она начинается от и.е. корня),  а в современном языке мы рассматриваем  только **ее часть**.

Определить **исходное слово** не так просто, в частности такая задача решается у Тихонова (он обозначает все словообразовательное **гнездо**). Лингвисты и те не всегда согласны друг с другом, а что же делать пользователям, тем более школьникам.

Надо знать **принятую норму** (это базовые знания), а углубленные знания можно получить, сравнивая разные решения и понимая, на чем они основаны. И вот своя **словарная статья** для слова  — это уже факт, из которого можно сделать вывод, что слово стало самостоятельным.

Если пользователь и с этим не согласен, то это уже его проблемы. Если в дальнейшем он планирует **изучать лингвистику**, гуманитарные науки, то может работать с этой темой дальше. Но это может быть **школьник**, который интересуется биологией, физикой, математикой, ему такое углубленное изучение не нужно. А вот знать предмет **в базовом варианте** необходимо.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Статья **о разных методах** морфемного анализа и **разных программах обучения** в школе (методы структурный, семантический и переходный между ними) https://studfile.net/preview/7634279/page:40/

**Морфемный состав основы.** Разбор слова по составу

Возможны два противоположных подхода к морфемному членению слова: **формально-структурный и формально-семантический.**

**Формально-структурный подход** к морфемному членению слова не является исключительно принадлежностью школьной практики. Аналогичный подход осуществлен **в ряде научных изданий**, например в «Словаре морфем русского языка» А. И. Кузнецовой и Т. Ф. Ефремовой, где утверждается, что **«морфемный анализ мало зависит от словообразовательного,** так как обычно при членении слова используется сопоставительный метод, при котором практически не учитывается, что от чего образуется».

Формально-структурному подходу противопоставлен **подход формально-семантический.** Главная установка данного подхода и алгоритм морфемного разбора выходят из трудов Г. О. Винокура и состоят **в неразрывности морфемного членения и словообразовательного разбора**. О том, что этот подход является **целесообразным и даже единственно возможным**, писали многие ученые и методисты на протяжении многих десятилетий.

Подход **учебных комплексов** к вопросу о принципах и алгоритме морфемного членения различен.

В учебниках учебного комплекса 1 в изданиях **70-х и 80-х годов** подход к морфемному разбору был исключительно **формально-структурный.**

Повторное обращение к морфемному разбору **на более сложном языковом материале** осуществляется после изучения способов словообразования.

Таким образом, **три комплекса в** вопросе о принципах морфемного членения занимают принципиально **разную позицию**: максимально семантизированную и опирающуюся на словообразовательный разбор в комплексе 3, промежуточно в комплексе 1 и формально-структурную, предлагающую практически **субморфное членение** слова в комплексе 2.

**Субморфы** тождественны **морфам** данного языка, но только по форме; значения они не имеют.

Comment: 1)Исторический корень здесь отсутствует, потому что связи живы. 2)Словообразовательный разбор является подосновой для морфемного, если мы не можем найти производящее слово посредством толкования значения, значит связи умерли, и появилось новое слово (гнездо). 3)Тихонов отнюдь не аксиома, о чем уже неоднократно заявлялось и на форуме, и на «Грамоте.ру» специалистами. 4)Школьник делает такие разборы без словаря, потому он должен руководствоваться языковой логикой, а не псевдорекомендациями.

Comment: В школе учат именно СЛОВООБРАЗОВАТЕЛЬНОМУ разбору. Взять пресловутого «преподавателя», в котором приставки включены вашим ненаглядным в состав корня. Но вам любой мало-мальски образованный преподаватель скажет, что преподаватель – это тот, кто дает знания, и это верная логика.

Comment: А если ученик в 4-м классе учится, то чем он должен руководствоваться))

Comment: В 4 классе таких слов не дадут. Там учат делать простейшие выводы на основе сопоставления слов.

Comment: https://udarenieru.ru/index.php?word=on&morph_word=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C Если следовать вашей логике, то, сказав "ставить на путь истины", мы употребим совершенно иное слово, которое никак не связано с наставить, верно?

Comment: Это у Тихонова такая логика. Очень правильная логика! А вы еще подумайте об этом, а лучше задайте вопрос на форуме. В комментариях развернутые обсуждения не приветствуются. И кстати, приведите словарь или ссылки на учебники с вашим разбором проблемных слов.

Comment: Я вам только что объяснил, даже привел пример со словом "преподаватель". Логика Тихонова ничего не стоит. Почитайте школьные учебники на этот счет.

Comment: И по поводу класса, где учится школьник. Скорее всего, это младшее или среднее школьное звеню Современные старшеклассники редко советуются с родителями, считают себя самостоятельными. А вы приводите ДОКАЗАТЕЛЬСТВА, то есть ссылки на весь материал. Хотите доказать,что нормой является корень СТАВ? Пожалуйста, где словари и учебники, где ссылки на мнения специалистов. Хотелось бы знать, кто именно поддерживает эту точку зрения. только и всего.

Comment: Интересная этимология у английского слова stand, живые связи с нашим "стоять"? А у глагола understand какая этимология?  Ладно, до свидания.

Comment: www.etymonline.com/word/*sta-

Answer (score 1):

Наставник - корень, как минимум, СТа. Или праиндоевропейский [*sta](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*sta-).

Наставник очевидно от глагола наставлять.

Даль:

> НАСТАВЛЯТЬ, наставить чего, куда или на что; ставить, становить во
> множестве...

То есть уже по Далю корень став. Но если порассуждать еще немного, то
однокоренными будут: стая, ставить, стан, стать... Но скорее всего туда же пойдут и стоять, стол, стойло, столб и тд. То есть, что-то находящееся при основе, частица соединенное с чем-то большим.

Но в ЕГЭ нужно выделять, конечно, настав-, потому что это, как много других недокорней, исключение в нынешней системе псевдообразования.

То есть, алгоритм нахождения корней в ЕГЭ - найти ближайший глагол, попытаться отбросить приставку суффикс, сохранив семантическое значение, если не получается, то считать этот кусок слова корнем, помня при этом, что это не корень, а, как еще недавно говорили "основа".

Так что дело не в том, кто прав, а в том, что на ЕГЭ это посчитают ошибкой(может быть, так видимо считает учительница, но я не уверен).

ста+ть>ставить-ставленник>наставлять>наставник.

Comment: Можно и с законами не соглашаться, но вот нарушать их не рекомендуется. И призывать к нарушению законов тоже нельзя. А если я считаю, что это псевдозаконы? Тогда надо перебираться в другой штат, в другое государство или на Луну.

Comment: @Sharon почему? просто нужно держать в уме, что есть область псевдозаконов и псевдоязыка, а есть сам по себе язык и законы. Это немного сложнее, чем делить мир на черное и белое, но тоже можно жить, а что делать? Псевдо- кстати, это не тоже самое, что ложное, псевдо - это греческое слово, "ошибочно претендующее на истину" или как пишут англичане, на "авторитетность", дело в том, что ЕГЭ - это просто тест, который ни на какую истину не претендует.

Comment: Дело не в ЕГЭ и не  в конкретном учителе, а в разных подходах к анализу в школе (формальный, семантический и нечто среднее между ними). В разных учебных программах используются разные варианты, поэтому надо знать, по какой программе учится школьник. Учитель, вероятно, это знает. Эти программы описаны, например, а этой статье  https://studfile.net/preview/7634279/page:40/

Comment: Вот еще интересная стать о межъязыковых связях s-yaroslav.livejournal.com/164122.html stand – стоять

Comment: @Sharon да, интересно, я не уверен, что все это пересекается и переводится именно так, но скорее всего слова родственные. Однако в русском это не совсем твёрдый, а скорее устойчивый, что-то находящее вместе, потому стая и стадо. И я не уверен, что в протоиндоевропейском это было именно, то слово, как его поняли англичане "твердый". Потом есть столб, тоже ст+сонорный и почему то б, то в английском будет stake, который пишет от праинд-евр. *steg- , хотя тут никаких комментариев по этому нет. А камень у них stone, а у нас нет. и вообще, эта часть похожа на англосаксонское творчество.

Comment: При том что дальше они пишут, мол греческий стир (пер.жир), каким боком не ясно. И стена наша, то есть стоун ~ стена. Хотя с точки зрения плотный, потому что заСТывший и стена и жир с этой стороны можно как-то понять. Так что в этом плане русский намного более связанный язык, и эта чехарда с этимологическими корнями, не более чем попытка эти связи разрушить, хотя вряд ли получится.

Comment: Так что англичане идут в правильном направлении, часто, но интерпретации мне не кажутся верными, потому что глагольная логика сильнее, чем вещественная.

Comment: Да, наш язык более связанный, и это мне нравится.  Так, твОрог – твердый, потому что застывший:  структура его стоит на месте, не шевелится.  Так лучше понимаешь и чувствуешь каждое слово.

Comment: @Sharon творог, мне кажется, не совсем твердый, а скорее от творожный - ворожить, творить~, варить. Твердый тоже от творить скорее всего. То есть что-то преобразованное из жидкости? Недавно был вопрос, родственные ли слова оригами и орегано. Оказывается орегано - это орос и ганос. Вот только орос перевели как гора, хотя это скорее граница/край, грань, из-за ярких соцветий душицы, а ганос - яркий. А оригами - это не сложенная бумага, а бумага с четкими границами, граненая. Получается ор/гор/хор - вполне себе распространенный мультикультурный корень. Но это если не привязываться к вещам.

Comment: А в английском очень много именно вещей, а не образов. Другое вообще восприятие мира у западных людей. С другой стороны в русском, само слово имеет много разных форм, то есть по сути, слово-образ уже абстрактно и склоняет говорящего к абстракции. В английском же слово именно находится в связки только с рядом значений, причем жестко, и даже больше, есть слова прямо плохие, есть слова хорошие. В русском языке плохое или хорошее значение может быть у формы слова, а не у самого слова и тем более у корня. Поэтому этот семантический подход, через признаки и синонимы подобных не работает.

Answer (score 1):

1. Почему же лингвисты **меняли свое мнение**, неужели были такими беспринципными. Нет, не в этом дело. Со временем **менялся ПОДХОД** к морфемному анализу, от более простого к более сложному и научно обоснованному.

**О трех подходах** к анализу в соответствии со временем, с уровнем подготовки школьников и с их возрастными возможностями написано **[в следующей статье](https://studfile.net/preview/7634279/page:40/).**

2. Сначала морфемный анализ был **формально-структурным,** в такой форме он более доступен детям. Разберем слово ***на/став/ник***:  здесь легко увидеть приставку «на-», корень «став», суффикс «-ник», это доступно младшим школьникам, это их **первый опыт.**

**Формально-семантический анализ** более сложен, так как соотнесен со словообразовательным анализом, и это уже следующий этап, который могут освоить школьники **старших классов.** Там разбор выглядит следующим образом: ***настав/ник.***

**Цитата из статьи:** «О том, что этот подход является целесообразным и даже единственно возможным, писали **многие ученые и методисты** на протяжении многих десятилетий».

3. Да, это уже менее очевидно и вызывает определенный протест здравого смысла у пользователей. Так в чем же **ценность** такого подхода? Здесь точно зафиксирован момент **качественного изменения смысла слова**, а именно переход от **пространственного** значения «ставить, располагать» к значению **«учить, наставлять»**. Иначе этого и не заметишь!

Но искать знакомые приставки и корни — это начальное, но тоже **важное** умение. Как же тут быть? Может, лингвистам разделить морфемный анализ на два варианта: структурный и семантический?

4. Но пока виды анализа еще не разделили, а разделили **методики школьных программ.** Существуют **три методики** в соответствии со структурным, семантическим и переходным видом  морфемного анализа,  и каждая школа работает по выбранной методике.

Соответственно, **учитель должен разъяснить** школьникам эту ситуацию.  А иначе они будут доказывать свою правоту, предъявлять свои аргументы, находить разные решения в словарях. Так нужны ли **такие разборки?** Думаю, что нет.

5. **Цитата из статьи:** Таким образом, три комплекса в вопросе о принципах морфемного членения занимают принципиально **разную позицию**: максимально схематизированную и опирающуюся на словообразовательный разбор в комплексе 3, промежуточно в комплексе 1 и формально-структурную, предлагающую практически субморфное членение слова в комплексе 2.

Для справок: ***Субморфы*** тождественны морфам данного языка, но только по форме; значения они не имеют. Стоит задуматься о единственно правильном **субморфном анализе**, который здесь предлагается.

Comment: Вам бы тексты для сочинений в формате ЕГЭ подбирать, чудесно бы вышло, как мне кажется.

Comment: Ага, талантище! Так и хочется что-нибудь сочинить. Я подумаю.

Comment: @Ajgy, вы иронизируете, а ведь Sharon пишет о профессиональном подходе. И делаете это грамотно, с пониманием.