# Как образовался глагол «наставить» в значении «научить, дать наставление»?

Tags: синтаксис, словообразование

Глагол ***наставить*** с пространственным значением образовался **префиксальным (приставочным**) способом от глагола ***ставить***  — это образование нового слова путем присоединения префикса (приставки) к производящей основе.

У него **четыре значения**, при этом от глагола с основным значением образуются глаголы с разными значениями **лексико-семантическим способом**. Это распад значений многозначного слова с образованием отдельных лексических единиц.

**Самое походящее значение 4**: наставить (что на кого-что). Направить на кого-, что-л., в кого-, что-л.; нацелить. Н. на вошедшего пистолет.

Глагол ***наставить*** (научить) образован **способом переноса** пространственного значения на пространство понятий: научить, передать знание. Но такой метод отсутствует в грамматике, а глагол получает свою **словарную статью**.

Можно ли тогда выделять в глаголе ***наставить*** приставку НА и считать производящей основу глагола "ставить": ***ставить — на/ставить — на/став/ник.***

[https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474896/О-корне-в-слове-наставник](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474896/%D0%9E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA)

**Приложение**

**1. НАСТАВИТЬ,** св. 1. что и кого-чего. Поставить, расположить, разместить где-л. в каком-л. (обычно большом) количестве. Н. десяток сторожей у каждой двери. 2. чего. Разг. Наделать (побоями, ударами и т.п.). Н. синяков, шишек. Кто ж тебе таких фонарей под глазом наставил? 3. что. Приставив, присоединив что-л., удлинить; надставить. Н. платье, верёвку, штору. 4. что на кого-что. Направить на кого-, что-л., в кого-, что-л.; нацелить. Н. на вошедшего пистолет.

**2. НАСТАВИТЬ**,  св. (кого) на что и чему. Книжн. Научить кого-л. чему-л. хорошему; дать наставления (2 зн.). Н. заблудшего на путь истинный. Н. добру и правде. Н. на ум (разг.; вразумить).

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148316/discussion-on-question-by-sharon-------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.