Почему с приставками ПО и НА возникают проблемы при морфемном анализе глаголов?
Действительно, почему именно с этими приставками? Что в них особенного?

Из Вашего, Sharon, ответа (см. ниже): «Приставка НА

тоже интересная приставка. Вот предложение: Он учится в университете на факультете журналистики. Почему здесь разные приставки? Приставка В имеет конкретное пространственное значение (внутри чего-либо, имеющего сложную структуру), а у приставки НА значение обобщенное». === Гм… По-моему, и В и НА в Вашем примере никак нельзя называть приставками… Это ПРЕДЛОГИ.


В отличие от других приставок, «по» «может обозначать только завершенность действия». Такое обобщение содержит первый абзац ответа. Заметим, что под это обобщение не подпадает большое число глаголов, например:
по/мог/ать и по/так/ать, по/зна/ва/ть и по/ясн/ять - по/уч/ать - по/правл/ять - по/давл/ять, по/ну/кать -по/нужд/ать - по/сыл/ать и по/шевел/иваться - по/торапл/иваться, по/жир/ать глазами и по/сматр/ивать - по/гляд/ывать искоса, по/прош/айничать - по/бир/аться и по/да/вать, по/полн/ять и по/мещ/ать(ся), по/чит/ать - по/лаг/аться, по/ворач/ивать, по/ба/иваться, по/еж/иваться....

Приставка ПО
Приставка ПО в глаголе положить уже обсуждалась.  В отличие от других приставок, она может обозначать  только завершенность действия, то есть использоваться для образования видовых пар,  например: класть — положить.
Но ведь другие приставки обычно тоже меняют вид глагола? Да, меняют, но имеют еще дополнительное смысловое значение.  Поэтому они образуют морфемный квадрат и выделяются при разборе,  хотя глагола ложить в нормированном варианте нет.
Приставка НА

Наиболее часто приставка НА используется в двух прямых значениях:  (1) разместить сверху предмета, на его поверхности; (2) поместить в большом количестве (образно говоря, одно на другое).

И вот известные примеры, где возникают споры при разборе: наслед/ник и настав/ник. Тихонов приставку не выделяет,  а почему? Учитываются словообразовательные связи.


Наследник.  Как образовать наследник от след? Следить — наследить — наследовать. Нет, здесь приставка НА в наследить обозначает избыточность действия,  а не направленность.  Это неверная схема.
Другой вариант: след — следовать — наследовать.  Здесь приставка НА имеет значение направленности, но глагол следовать непереходный, в отличие от наследовать. Опять неверная схема. Соответственно, сложный корень НАСЛЕД- образует новое гнездо.
Наставник.  Ставить — наставить (чего-то в большом количестве) — наставлять (научить кого-то чему-то).  Неверная словообразовательная схема и тот же вывод: выделяется сложный корень НАСТАВ-.

А почему в глаголе наложить не выделена приставка? Здесь-то верны оба значения?  В качестве версии: в толковом словаре указано сильное управление двумя дополнениями, например:
НАЛОЖИТЬ, св. 1. что на что. Положить сверху, 
поверх чего-л. Н. кальку на чертёж. Н. лекало на 
фанеру. Н. выкройку на ткань.



P. S.  На форуме  разбор Тихонова наслед/ник привел к особенно активному осуждению и неприятию его решения.
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474896/О-корне-в-слове-наставник
Цитирую:
Соответственно, ваша дочь не сделала никакой 
ошибки: корень "став" здесь можно и нужно выделить. 
ГЛУПОСТЬ - верить необоснованным мнениям. 

Эти участник, который позволил себе резкие высказывания против словаря Тихонова (да и против Потихи тоже, у него тот же разбор настав/ник) предлагал свои собственные субъективные суждения взамен решению  лингвистов, а также утверждал право школьника делать разбор по своему разумению. И за  ответы с выделенной приставкой НА, чего нет ни в одном из последних изданий словарей, было подано 10 голосов. Этот ответ  считается лучшим и определяет престиж форума.
Да и сейчас голосование против Тихонова продолжается. И мне неловко за тех, кто молча ставит эти галочки, не объясняя своих мотивов. И неловко за тех, кто хочет решить  вопрос о правке словаря Тихонова, минуя РАН.

Sharon: «…и определяет престиж форума». === Sharon, престиж форума падает в первую очередь из-за Ваших ответов. См., к примеру, первую редакцию Вашего ответа в этой теме, исправленную после моего замечания. Могу напомнить и про недавно удалённый Вами (после моей критики) один из  Ваших ответов в теме «Корень слова ПОЛОЖИТЬ». Может, вернёте его для всеобщего обозрения?

А все и так видят, если у них достаточно репутации. чтобы увидеть. Я рада,что вы умеете отличать предлоги от приставок, это уже большое достижение.  Кроме того, значение приставок и одноименных предлогов сходны, и я могла бы просто скорректировать этот пункт. В любом случае, я удаляю то, что не считаю нужным ОСТАВЛЯТЬ на нашем учебном ресурсе.  А откровения вашего друга до сих пор там красуются.  Если ученик хочет доказать свою точку зрения, он должен это делать грамотно, анализируя разные ПРИНЦИПЫ разбора (а их два!), а не с помощью ссылок на УСТАРЕВШИЕ издания словарей, как делаете вы

Вы видите, что разбор слова во всех словарях стал только таким: НАСТАВ/НИК, вот в чем вред. // Здесь я привожу сравнительный анализ и корректный ответ, в том числе по той теме, который можно сформулировать в трех предложениях. Переход к семантическому методу был ПОСТЕПЕННЫМ, лингвисты меняли свою точку зрения. Вы же предлагаете в своем ответе читать устаревшие редакции словарей. В ваших ответах с фотографиями отсутствует такой анализ, который вы в данном случае переложили на ученика.  // Дискуссию на этом считаю закрытой и оставляю за собой право удалять и изменять все, что считаю нужным.

Sharon: «Вы видите, что разбор слова во всех словарях стал только таким: НАСТАВ/НИК…» === Sharon, это слово присутствует не во всех словарях. К примеру, в школьном словаре Баранова, который я приводил в своём ответе в той теме, его нет. Зато в нём есть однокоренное с НАСТАВНИКОМ слово НАСТАВЛЕНИЕ, разбираемое в словаре так: НА/СТАВЛ/ЕНИ/Е. Так что не всё так однозначно…

Вы СЕЙЧАС посмотрите слово настав/ник в словарях Тихонова и Потихи и дайте школьнику ОТВЕТ, как это слово нужно разбирать. В том числе расскажите по ЛИТНЕВСКОЙ о двух принципах разбора, о чем вы никогда не вспоминаете.  По этим двум словарям работают в школе, не правда ли?  И не посылайте их очень далеко, когда речь идет об обычном школьном разборе. А про разбор "наставление" задайте отдельный вопрос, и лучше на Грамоте.

Помимо того, что постоянно говорить о двух принципах, нужно уметь их ещё и правильно применять. Позвольте вспомнить комментарий, адресованный Вам в той теме: «мне думается, что человек, написавший в этой теме, что «в толковом словаре уже есть глагол наставить (научить), он стал самостоятельным, получил собственную словарную статью. Поэтому при разборе мы включаем приставку НА в состав корня», не должен был бы давать советы школьникам по морфемному разбору и словообразовательному разборам. Не дай бог кто-то из школьников воспользуется его утверждениями!»

До свидания, участник Слава. Наша дискуссия закончена.  Я сказала то, что вы дали ответ, НЕ СООТВЕТСТВУЮЩИЙ ДВУМ ОСНОВНЫМ СЛОВАРЯМ, причем знали об этом.  Этого достаточно! НЕ НАРУШАЙТЕ ПРАВИЛА САЙТА, пройдите в чат, и остальное пишите там. Пожалуйста, не беспокойте меня
