Можно ли с помощью толкового словаря проверить правильность морфемного разбора?
РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
К примеру, нужно разобрать слово настав/ник.  В словарях Потихи и Тихонова  дается однозначный вариант без выделения приставки НА, хотя в некоторых случаях решения по этим словарям не совпадают.
Но школьники могут предложить такой вариант: на/став/ник.
Можно ли проверить  правильность морфемного разбора по толковому словарю?

РУССКИЙ ЯЗЫК НА SE
Толковый словарь можно использовать  при морфемном анализе для доказательства правильности решения.
Из статьи

МНОГОЗНАЧНОСТЬЮ, или полисемией (гр. poly — много + sma — знак), называется свойство слов употребляться в разных значениях. В словарной статье под одним заголовком приводится перечень значений многозначного слова, что обозначено цифрами. Многозначное слово отражается в одной словарной статье.

Из учебника Литневской: Разные значения одного слова помещаются в одну словарную статью толкового словаря.

Лексико-семантический способ словообразования

Лексико-семантический способ словообразования представляет собой распад значений многозначного слова. Значения слова расходятся по смыслу настолько далеко друг от друга, что образуют отдельные лексические единицы. Так в русском языке возникают омонимы:

Итак, если у слова две словарные статьи, то такие слова являются омонимами, и это уже разные слова с различным смыслом и разными способами образования.

Рассмотрим глагол наставить, от которого образовано существительное наставник. У него две словарные статьи.


Слово наставить (1)  образуется  следующим образом: ставить — на/ставить, поэтому в нем выделена приставка НА. Слово многозначное, но такой разбор верен для всех значений слова.
Слово наставить (2) является самостоятельным словом, к глаголу ставить по способу образования не относится и образует собственное словообразовательное гнездо, в котором является непроизводным словом. Поэтому приставка НА не выделяется в этом слове, а сливается с корнем.
Таким образом, верен именно такой  морфемный разбор, и проверить это можно с помощью толкового словаря.
1. НАСТАВИТЬ, -влю, -вишь; св. 1. что и кого-чего. 
Поставить, расположить, разместить где-л. в каком- 
л. (обычно большом) количестве. Н. десяток сторожей 
у каждой двери. Наставили тут мебели - не пройдёшь! 
2. чего. Разг. Наделать (побоями, ударами и т.п.). 
Н. синяков, шишек. Кто ж тебе таких фонарей под 
глазом наставил? 3. что. Приставив, присоединив 
что-л., удлинить; надставить. Н. платье, верёвку, 
штору. // Приставить, присоединить для удлинения 
чего-л. Н. кусок ткани к рукаву. 4. что на кого- 
что. Направить на кого-, что-л., в кого-, что-л.; 
нацелить. Н. на вошедшего пистолет. 


2. НАСТАВИТЬ, -влю, -вишь; св. (кого) на что и 
чему. Книжн. Научить кого-л. чему-л. хорошему; дать 
наставления (2 зн.). Н. заблудшего на путь 
истинный. Н. добру и правде. Н. на ум (ум-разум); 
н. уму-разуму (разг.; вразумить). Наставлять, -яю, 
-яешь; нсв. Наставление (см.).


Присоединяюсь к вашему ответу.

Серж, огромное вам спасибо за поддержку!  Я очень ценю ваше мнение как  специалиста в области лингвистики.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
Поводом для написания материала послужил следующий комментарий нашего участника из темы https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474896/О-корне-в-слове-наставник
В недавней теме он еще раз напомнил мне об этом: вы не должны давать советы школьникам по морфемному разбору. Ни много ни мало, как не должна!  В той же теме не был принят ответ с разбором по Тихонову — настав/ник.
   @Sharon, мне думается, что человек, написавший в этой 
   теме, что «в толковом словаре уже есть глагол наставить 
   (научить), он стал самостоятельным, получил собственную 
   словарную статью. Поэтому при разборе мы включаем 
   приставку НА в состав корня», не должен был бы давать 
   советы школьникам по морфемному разбору и 
   словообразовательному разборам. Не дай бог кто-то из 
   школьников воспользуется его утверждениями! – 
    Слава  29 авг. 2023 в 8:19 

А это другой участник, ныне ушедший с форума, высказывает эту мысль в оригинале, 27 авг. 2023
  P.S. С каких пор аргументом стало то, что в словаре 
  присутствует слово с приставкой?

Так была сказана фраза о том, что нет никакой связи между словарной статьей в толковом словаре и морфемным разбором. Тогда я предположила, что такая связь существует, а в этой теме доказываю это.
